# Inserting text in a textarea with the function .click() - text disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I was trying to get the value from the tag 'value' of an input and insert it in a textarea. Which I succeded BUT...
The text lasts only the time of the click.

Here's the code :

```
   $(function(){
    $("input.hiragana").click(function() {
        document.getElementById('hiraganaBoard').append($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Example of an input :

```
<input class = 'hiragana' type = 'submit' value = 'あ' />
```

hiraganaBoard is a `textarea`.

(just in case you needed the html part, quite huge so I just paste that)

(PS: code kinda inspired by the research I did before asking the question btw. But I may used the wrong terms I don't know. I apologize if I missed the answer. Thanks for your understanding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.append in jQuery refers to the actual element, whereas we an to change the value.  Using .append instead of .val will break it immediately after the user enters any text.

```js
$(".insert").click(function() {
 $("#here").val($("#here").val() + $(this).attr("value"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="here"></textarea>

<button class="insert" value = 'あ'>あ</button>
```

Comment: Not working, nothing happens. Here is the modified code :
`document.getElementById('hiraganaBoard').val(document.getElementById('hiraganaBoard').val() + $(this).val());`

Comment: Try the new version of it, just changed it

Comment: Comment if you need more help, or just mark as answer if it's good.

Comment: Im still struggling to make it works. It doesn't act like in your snippet. I will comment if I make it works dont worry ^^. It still disappears after the click ends.

Comment: I changed some of your HTML to make it easier.  For instance, the button now has the class insert and then it also has the value of your special character.  I did this so it would be easy to add additional characters.  All you have to do is add <button class="insert" value="newCharacter">click me to add newCharacter</button> to insert it into the textarea.  Try copying and pasting my code and then modify it as you please.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your code(Im trying it with inputs) :) but I really needs to stay on 'inputs'. Can I still make it works with them ?

Comment: Yeah, but buttons are better.

Comment: I decided to make an example:  https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/2uy9sp44/ ...  If I'm honest, please just use buttons.  But if you want https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/2uy9sp44/ is how you do inputs

Comment: That's weird. Why does it works on your snippets while I'm getting the value disappearing when I tries it >< . Thanks for taking your time for me anyway :) !
`$(function(){
 $(".hiragana").click(function() {
  $("#hiraganaBoard").val($("#hiraganaBoard").val() + $(this).attr("value"));
 });
});`

Comment: Resolved ! It was a veryyyy dumb mistake. So dumb that I'm ashamed to post but... In fact my textarea was in a form... And I let imagine what happent... Really sorry and thanks for your answer !